# Creating a set<char> in C++

Tags: c++, initialization

I am coding this thing and it would be helpful to have a `static const set<char>` containing some elements that won't change.

```
class MyClass {
     private:
         static const set<char> mySet = ??  
}
```

How can I do this? It would be nice if you could create them from a string, like `mySet("ABC")`, but I can't get the syntax to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this will work just fine:

```
// my_class.h
class MyClass
{
  static const std::set<char> mySet;
};

// my_class.cpp
const char *tmp = "ABCDEFGHI";
const std::set<char> MyClass::mySet(tmp,tmp+strlen(tmp));
```

Comment: +1, I totally forgot about range-based initialization. Certainly works well if it can be easily expressed as a range, but works not-so-well if it contains some computation.

Comment: If you write `const char tmp[] = "ABCDEFGHI";`, you can use `sizeof(tmp)-1` (which is an Integral Constant Expression)

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following ought to work..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct foo
{
  static std::set<char> init_chars();

  static const std::set<char> myChars;
};

const std::set<char> foo::myChars = foo::init_chars();

std::set<char> foo::init_chars()
{
  std::string sl("ABDCEDFG");
  return std::set<char>(sl.begin(), sl.end());
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << foo::myChars.size() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize the variable inside the class, because it technically hasn't been defined yet (only declared).

In the class, keep `static const set<char> mySet;`.

In the implementation (i.e. .cpp file):

```
const char[] _MyClassSetChars = "ABC";

// Define and initialize the set, using
// the constructor that takes a start and end iterator
const set<char> MyClass::mySet(
    _MyClassSetChars,
    _MyClassSetChars + sizeof(_MyClassSetChars) / sizeof(_MyClassSetChars[0])
);
```

This also includes the terminating null character (`\0`) in the set, which is probably not what you want -- instead, use this:

```
const set<char> MyClass::mySet(
    _MyClassSetChars,
    _MyClassSetChars + (sizeof(_MyClassSetChars) / sizeof(_MyClassSetChars[0]) - 1)
);
```

Note that here you can use `<cstring>`'s `strlen()` (as per [Let_Me_Be's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543797/creating-a-setchar-in-c/5543876#5543876)) in place of the more general form above:

```
const set<char> MyClass::mySet(
    _MyClassSetChars,
    _MyClassSetChars + strlen(_MyClassSetChars)
);
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197106/static-constructors-in-c-need-to-initialize-private-static-objects).

Comment: Aren't you adding one character to much?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `static set <const char> mySet;` ? Of course you need to initialize it first otherwise if you try to `insert` after you declare your `set`, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
header file:
#include<set>
class MyClass {
private:
    static const std::set<char> mySet;
}

source file:
#include<boost/assign.hpp>
const MyClass::mySet = boost::assign::list_of('A')('B')('C');
```