# How to initialise a static member variable "dynamically"?

Tags: c++, static-members

How can I initialise a static member variable "dynamically"?

For instance, I declare this variable in the header file of a class:

```
class MyPermutation {
    static std::array<std::vector<uint8_t>,2> permutation_list;
};
```

And I want it to have the following values:

```
permutation_list[0] = std::vector<uint8_t>{0};
permutation_list[1] = std::vector<uint8_t>{};
for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
    permutation_list[1].push_back( 1<<i );
```

Where should I put the above code?

Comment: Maybe that can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197106/static-constructors-in-c-need-to-initialize-private-static-objects

Answer (score 3):

this is usually done by a function that is called to initialize the static variable:

```
std::array<std::vector<uint8_t>,2> MyPermutation::permutation_list = someFunctionThatBuildsTheInitialValues();
```

Or, since C++11, it can be a lambda:

```
std::array<std::vector<uint8_t>,2> MyPermutation::permutation_list = 
  []() -> std::array<std::vector<uint8_t>,2> {
    std::array<std::vector<uint8_t>,2> the_list;
    the_list[0] = std::vector<uint8_t>{0};
    the_list[1] = std::vector<uint8_t>{};
    for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
      the_list[1].push_back( 1<<i );
    /* ... */
    return the_list;
  }();
```