# Boost logging class attribute

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I am trying to do a log for my application. I want to add an attribute so I would know in what class is the log. I have starting a test to see if it works:

```
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/syslog_backend.hpp>

enum severity_levels
{
    debug,
    info,
    warning,
    error
};

typedef boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink< boost::log::sinks::syslog_backend > SinkSysLogBackEnd;
typedef boost::log::sources::severity_logger< severity_levels > BoostLogger;

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& strm, severity_levels level)
{
    static const char* strings[] =
    {
        "debug",
        "info",
        "warning",
        "error"
    };

    if (static_cast< std::size_t >(level) < sizeof(strings) / sizeof(*strings))
        strm << strings[level];
    else
        strm << static_cast< int >(level);

    return strm;
}

BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(severity, "Severity", severity_levels)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(executable, "Executable", std::string)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(className, "Class name", std::string)

void init_syslog()
{
    // Create a backend
    boost::shared_ptr< SinkSysLogBackEnd > sink(new SinkSysLogBackEnd());

    // We'll have to map our custom levels to the syslog levels
    boost::log::sinks::syslog::custom_severity_mapping< severity_levels > mapping("Severity");
    mapping[info] = boost::log::sinks::syslog::info;
    mapping[warning] = boost::log::sinks::syslog::warning;
    mapping[error] = boost::log::sinks::syslog::error;

    sink->set_formatter(
        boost::log::expressions::stream
        // line id will be written in hex, 8-digits, zero-filled
        << executable << " <" << severity
        << "> : " << boost::log::expressions::smessage);

    sink->locked_backend()->set_severity_mapper(mapping);

    // Set the remote address to sent syslog messages to
    sink->locked_backend()->set_target_address("localhost");

    // Wrap it into the frontend and register in the core.
    // The backend requires synchronization in the frontend.
    boost::log::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
}

class Cls1
{
    BoostLogger m_lg;
public:
    Cls1()
    {
        // set the class name to Cls1
    }

    void foo()
    {
        // print log that has "Class Name" attribute set to "Cls1"
    }
};

class Cls2
{
    BoostLogger m_lg;
public:
    Cls2()
    {
        // set the class name to Cls2
    }


    void foo()
    {
        // print log that has "Class Name" attribute set to "Cls2"
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    init_syslog();

    Cls1 o1;
    o1.foo();
    Cls2 o2;
    o2.foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Now I am stuck...

1. How it would be better to do?
2. How to set the attribute to the wanted value?
3. Shall I do the BoostLogger members static?

Thanks for any advice. I have seen the boost log attributes tutorial ([link1](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/attributes.html), [link2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial.html), [link3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/attributes.html#log.detailed.attributes.related_components.attribute_set)), but I have not found something that would help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved the problem using static loggers for each class and using a method for initializing them. Something like this:

```
BoostLogger setClassNameAttribute(const std::string& classNameIn)
{
    BoostLogger lg;
    lg.add_attribute("ClassName", boost::log::attributes::constant<std::string>(classNameIn));
    return lg;
}
```

---

```
class Cls1
{
    static BoostLogger sm_lg;
public:
    Cls1()
    {
        // set the class name to Cls1
    }

    void foo()
    {
        // print log that has "Class Name" attribute set to "Cls1"
    }
};

BoostLogger Cls1::sm_lg = setClassNameAttribute("Cls1");
```

---

```
class Cls2
{
    static BoostLogger sm_lg;
public:
    Cls2()
    {
        // set the class name to Cls2
    }


    void foo()
    {
        // print log that has "Class Name" attribute set to "Cls2"
    }
};

BoostLogger Cls2::sm_lg = setClassNameAttribute("Cls2");
```

Comment: haha wow! we must have been writing our solutions at the same time! nice work though

Answer (score 8):

Below a sample that I programed:

Logger.hpp :

```
#ifndef LOGGER_HPP
#define LOGGER_HPP

#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/async_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/empty_deleter.hpp>

class Logger
{
public:

    typedef boost::log::sinks::asynchronous_sink<boost::log::sinks::text_ostream_backend> text_sink;

    Logger();

    ~Logger();

    void    Initialize();

    void    Finalize();

    void    addStream(boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream>& stream);

    template< typename T >
    Logger& operator<<(const T& value)
    {
        BOOST_LOG(my_logger::get()) << value;
        return *this;
    }

    typedef Logger& (*LoggerManipulator)(Logger&);

    Logger& operator<<(LoggerManipulator manip)
    {
        return manip(*this);
    }

    static Logger& endl(Logger& stream)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return stream;
    }


    typedef std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> CoutType;

    typedef CoutType& (*StandardEndLine)(CoutType&);

    Logger& operator<<(StandardEndLine manip)
    {
        manip(std::cout);
        return *this;
    }

private:

    boost::log::sources::logger_mt m_lg;

    boost::shared_ptr<text_sink> m_sink;

};

#endif LOGGER_HPP
```

Logger.cpp:

```
    #include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

    #include "Logger.hpp"

    Logger::Logger()
        :
        m_sink(new text_sink),
        m_lg()
    {
    }

    Logger::~Logger()
    {
    }

    void    Logger::Initialize()
    {
        m_sink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);

    m_sink->set_formatter
        (
        boost::log::expressions::format("[%1%] - %2%")
        % boost::log::expressions::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp")
        % boost::log::expressions::smessage
        );

    boost::log::core::get()->add_sink(m_sink);

    boost::log::core::get()->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp",boost::log::attributes::local_clock());
}

void    Logger::Finalize()
{
}

void    Logger::addStream(boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream>& stream)
{
    m_sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(stream);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main
{
    boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream> stream_out(&std::clog, boost::empty_deleter());
    boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream> stream_file(new std::ofstream(ProgramName + ".log", std::ostream::app));

    Logger logger;

    logger.addStream(stream_out);
    logger.addStream(stream_file);
    logger.Initialize();

    logger << "Sample";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you have in your code is what I have in mine (more or less), but I have 2 different classes that each has a logger member; what I want is that in each class the logger has a different value for the "Class name" attribute. How to do that, not how to have a logger?

Comment: This question explicitly asks about logging the class name as an attribute and you say nothing about it?!

Answer (score 2):

I've adapted the code from the documentation on [attributes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/attributes.html) and [formatting](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/formatters.html) to achieve a solution to this. I extracted all the relevant bits from my program to create the sample code below; It doesn't compile, but should give you a clear indication on what to do.

Rough explanation:

- Use `expressions::attr<string>("ClassName")` in the formatter somewhere
- Create a static logger for each class, of type such as `severity_logger<severity_level>`
- Create a static initializer using the technique [described by EFraim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1197143/1072869) (or some other technique) which adds the class name attribute to the logger like so: `logger.add_attribute("ClassName", attrs::constant<string>("Foo"));`
- Use the logger like so: `BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, trace) << "Hello there";`

I've left out a lot of the includes and 'using namespace's - let me know if you can't find where something comes from.

```
// I have this in my stdafx.h for convenience
typedef boost::log::sources::severity_logger<boost::log::trivial::severity_level> Logger;

// foo.h
class Foo
{
    private:
        static Logger logger;

        static class _Init
        {
        public:
            _Init()
            {
                logger.add_attribute("ClassName", boost::log::attributes::constant<std::string>("Foo"));
            }
        } _initializer;

    public:
        Foo();
}

// foo.cpp
Logger Foo::logger;                     // initialize the static variables
Foo::_Init Foo::_initializer;

Foo::Foo()
{
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, trace) << "Hello there";
}


// main.cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::log;

    // Set up our sink and formatting
    boost::log::add_file_log(
        boost::log::keywords::file_name = "MyApp_%3N.log",
        boost::log::keywords::rotation_size = 1 * 1024 * 1024,
        boost::log::keywords::max_size = 20 * 1024 * 1024,
        boost::log::keywords::time_based_rotation = boost::log::sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
        boost::log::keywords::format = 
        (
            expressions::stream 
            << expressions::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f") << "|"
            << expressions::attr<std::string>("ClassName") << "|"
            << trivial::severity << "|"
            << expressions::message 
        ),
        boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true
        );

    boost::log::add_common_attributes();

    boost::log::core::get()->set_filter(
        boost::log::trivial::severity >= boost::log::trivial::trace
        );

    Foo* foo = new Foo();
}
```

The output will look something like

> 2014-08-26 19:16:19,006726|Foo|trace|Hello there

(I've formatted it like that because the log viewer I use likes it that way)

Now you should be able to sort your log messages by class name. :)

Comment: I have not used `Program::` before, can you give me a link about it?

Comment: oh sorry - its meant to be "Foo", I copied the code from my application which has a class named "Program"