# Dynamic struct names from string

Tags: c++, string, dynamic, types, struct

I have a string and want to use it as struct name dynamically.

```
struct employee{

atributes ....
} 

string name;
cin >>name;


employee "name"

and then use the named employee !
```

does not work

```
employee &name = new employee();
```

does not work

Comment: Where did you find the syntax `employee &name = new employee();`? C++ is not a language where you can write the first thing that comes to mind (even adapted from another language) and expect it to work. The best course of action isn't someone telling you the exact syntax, but learning from a good introductory book.

Comment: You can't do that. Perhaps you should explain what problem you are trying to solve that has caused you to come up with this proposed solution.

Comment: C++ is not javascript. One is static the other is dynamic, and you just stepped on one of the core differences :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible in C++. Look at the concept of [associative containers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_containers) to store named references to class/struct instances, for example an `std::map<std::string, employee>`. This [creates a 'map'](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) class mapping string based keys to values of type `employee`.

[More practical examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3578247/1729885).

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, you can't use run-time string values as variable names. You could use a [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to index objects by a string or other key type:

```
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, employee> employees;

employees[name] = employee();
```

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Uhm what?!?

Comment: Erm my bad, read too quick. Sorry  :)  Shouldn't pick up the phone while writing answers...