# I want to create something like a python dictionary in C++

Tags: python, c++

I'm using a struct. Is there some way to iterate through all the items of type "number"?

```
struct number { int value; string name; };
```

Comment: I'm not sure the question. In C++ we have "maps", i.e. `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`. [See here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) for a list of standard data structures.

Comment: If you want to create a python-like dictionary, then you want to implement a [hashmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented). So look into `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` as suggested both in the comments and answers sections. C++ implementation example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578083/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-a-hashmap-in-c).

Answer (score 10):

In c++ map works like python dictionary, But there is a basic difference in two languages. C++ is typed and python having duck typing. C++ Map is typed and it can't accept any type of (key, value) like python dictionary. 
A sample code to make it more clear -

```
  map<int, char> mymap;
  mymap[1] = 'a';
  mymap[4] = 'b';
  cout<<"my map is -"<<mymap[1]<<" "<<mymap[4]<<endl;
```

You can use tricks to have a map which will accept any type of key, Refer - http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/14982/

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding you want to access a `value` and `name` using `number`. You can go for `array of structure` like
`number n[5];` where `n[0],n[1],...n[4]`
but we have some additional features in c++ to achieve this with the predefined `map, set`
You can find lots of examples for map

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::map` (or `unordered_map`)

```
     //  Key  Value Types.
std::map<int, std::string> data {{1, "Test"}, {2, "Plop"}, {3, "Kill"}, {4, "Beep"}};

for(auto item: data) {
                 // Key                  Value
    std::cout << item.first << " : " << item.second << "\n";
}
```

Compile and run:

```
> g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp
> ./a.out
1 : Test
2 : Plop
3 : Kill
4 : Beep
```

The difference between `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` is for `std::map` the items are ordered by the `Key` while in `std::unordered_map` the values are not ordered (thus they will be printed in a seemingly random order).

Internally they use very different structures but I am sure you are not interested in that level of detail.