# How can I use a string read from `std::cin` to look up an existing variable by name?

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to make a sort of a shopping cart. When the program asks for items, i type them in; but it needs to remember the values so it can use them later in the code.

I have this code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int item{};
    int apple = 5;
    std::cout << "what item do you want to buy?";
    std::cin >> item;
    std::cout << item;
    return 0;
}
```

Can I make it so that when i type `apple` as input, `item` actually gets the value `5`, from the variable named `apple`? With this code, I get `0` as the result.

Comment: No, in C++ the name of a variable *only exists* while the code is being compiled (except perhaps for some debug-mode hacks designed to help find problems in the code). The program cannot look for the name `apple` because it is not actually stored anywhere that it could be found. Instead, use a data structure that explicitly does that mapping, such as `std::map`.

Comment: Hello, you can also check this post about hashmap in cpp
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578083/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-a-hashmap-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a [`map`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) with `string` keys and `int` values, store the necessary data in that map (instead of separate variables), and use the value read from `std::cin` as an index.

The code looks like:

```
std::map<std::string, int> fruits;
fruits["apple"] = 5;
std::string choice;
std::cin >> choice;
std::cout << fruits[choice] << std::endl;
```

Comment: yep thats it thnaks also if i wanted to add more values to fruits how would i do that?

Comment: The same way that the `apple` value is added.

Comment: would this work? fruits["apple", "grape"] = 5, 10; or something like this

Comment: No; use two separate statements.

Comment: Alternately, use this initialization syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138600/initializing-a-static-stdmapint-int-in-c

Comment: @MaravicKarlo `fruits["apple"] = 5; fruits["grape"] = 10;`

Comment: After reading `choice`, it will be necessary to check that the map contains an entry for that string before printing it.   Unless you want to create an entry for the string entered, and (depending on user input) have `fruits["apple"]` and `fruits["Apple"]` map to different values.

Comment: my bad im brain dead how would i make it so when i enter  more than one fruit it makes it sum up the price?

Comment: You should probably use `.at()` for reading from the map, which will protect you from using a wrong key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map, as shown in the other answer. Another choice would be to show the user a numbered list:

```
1: apple - $10
2: banana - $15
3: ...
```

And then ask them to enter a number. Then use the number to access the element in the array of products. This might be a more robust interface for the user.