# write a C construct

Tags: c, string, switch-statement, construct

Is there a way (in C) to write a construct like the `switch` statement, but for strings? Is there a way to write a C construct *at all* in C?

By C construct I mean a statement with braces ... like an `if` statement has braces, and it's a C construct... right?

Comment: Switching on strings is not possible in C. What do you mean by 'C construct'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is an if-else chain using `strcmp` to do the comparisons:

```
if (strcmp(str, "String 1") == 0)
  // do something
else if (strcmp(str, "String 2") == 0)
  // do something else
else if (strcmp(str, "String 3") == 0)
  // do something else 
...
else
  printf("%s not found\n", str);
```

A more complicated approach is to use a lookup table, keyed by the string:

```
struct lookup {const char *key; int value};

struct lookup LookupTable[] = {
  {"String 1", 1}, 
  {"String 2", 2}, 
  {"String 3", 3}, 
  ...
  {NULL, -1}
};

int lookup(const char *key)
{
  size_t i = 0;
  while (LookupTable[i].key != NULL)
    if (strcmp(str, LookupTable[i].key) == 0)
      return LookupTable[i].value;
    else
      i++;
  return -1;
}
...
switch(lookup(str))
{
  case 1: ...
  case 2: ...
  case 3: ...
  ...
  default: printf("%s not found\n", str); break;
}
```

If you want to get really fancy, you could modify the lookup table so that the value is a pointer to a function:

```
void String1Cmd(void) { ... }
void String2Cmd(void) { ... }
void String3Cmd(void) { ... }
...
void BadCmd(void) { printf("Key not found!\n"); }

struct lookup {char *key, void (*cmd)(void); };

struct lookup LookupTable[] = {
  {"String 1", String1Cmd}, 
  {"String 2", String2Cmd}, 
  {"String 3", String3Cmd}, 
  ...
  {NULL, BadCmd}
};

void (*lookup(const char *str))(void)
{
  size_t i = 0;
  while(LookupTable[i].key != NULL)
    if (strcmp(str, LookupTable[i].key) == 0)
      return LookupTable[i].cmd;
    else
      i++;
  return BadCmd;
}
...
void (*f)(void) = lookup(str); // retrieve the function for the given string
f(); // execute the function
```

In the last example, if `str` == "String 1", then `String1Cmd` will be executed.  If `str` is a string not found in the lookup table, then `BadCmd` will be executed.  This method is very flexible, and depending on your design, allows you to add behavior at runtime (sort of a plug-in architecture).

However, note that we've just deferred the main problem - branching on a string value - to the `lookup` function, and that the `lookup` function is back to just doing `strcmp` against each value in the table.  We could speed that part of the process up by using a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) or a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) to minimize the number of comparisons.  Depending on how many strings you're branching on, that may or may not be worth the additional effort.

Answer (score 3):

No, you have to do it yourself. There are many variants:

```
if (strcmp(str, "toto") == 0)
{
    // ...
}

else if (strcmp(str, "tata") == 0)
{
    // ...
}

else
{
    // ...
}
```

If the number of strings is expected to grow, then a dispatch table with function pointers

```
struct dispatch_entry
{
    const char *key;
    void (*action)(void);
};

// Make sure it is sorted !
dispatch_entry dispatch_table[] = 
{
    { "tata", &action_tata },
    { "toto", &action_toto },
};
```

coupled with binary search:

```
int dispatch_compare(const void *x, const void *y)
{
    const dispatch_entry *xx = x, *yy = y;
    return strcmp(xx->key, yy->key);
}

// Return -1 on failure
int dispatch(const char *str)
{
    static const size = sizeof(struct dispatch_entry);
    static const n = sizeof(dispatch_table) / size ;

    dispatch_entry tmp = { str, NULL };
    dispatch_entry *what = bsearch(tmp, dispatch_table, n, size, &dispatch_compare);

    if (what == NULL) return -1;

    (*what->action)();
    return 0;
}
```

will do. Hash table based approaches are OK as well.

Answer (score 2):

if you have the function **lfind** in your lib (POSIX or gcc) you can use it like:

```
  enum   { NOTFOUND, HELLO,  WORLD,  FOO,  BAR };
  char list[][100]={"hello","world","foo","bar"};

  size_t r, siz = sizeof*list, num = sizeof list/siz;

  char *tosearch = "foo";

  switch ( (r=lfind(tosearch,list,&num,siz,strcmp))?
          (r+siz-(size_t)list)/siz:0 )  {

    case HELLO: puts("hello");break;
    case WORLD: puts("world");break;
    case FOO:   puts("foo");  break;
    case BAR:   puts("bar");  break;
    case NOTFOUND:puts("not found");

  }
```

each string in the array must have the same size and should not be a pointer

Comment: I don't quite get what's going on here, as you don't name the `enum`, and please explain what is in the `switch` statement... And the `size_t` assignment.

Comment: switch returns the index+1 of the founded element in the Chararray-Array or 0, if not founded to cases; lfind makes the linear search in the (unsorted) array for you and returns the founded address; size_t is used for simple address-calculations

Answer (score 1):

a [hashtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) if you have a large number of strings and speed is an issue

Answer (score 1):

No, since the switch may only be used with integral types, or a type convertible to an integral type

Comment: One could write a function that searches the given string in a table of strings and returns its index, or -1. One could then switch on the returned index.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and the way is - long `if-else-if` statement. (for reference: [Why switch statement cannot be applied on strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650162/why-switch-statement-cannot-be-applied-on-strings) )

And what do you mean by "a C construct at all in C" o.O ? I'll edit my post, when you answer :)

Answer (score 0):

No, `switch` works on an integer value (I think floats/doubles are not even allowed). You can emulate that with if/else if/else doing `strcmp`.

```
if (strcmp(mystr, "this") == 0) {
    //mystr == "this"
}
else if (strcmp(mystr, "that") == 0) {
    //mystr == "that"
}
else {
   //mystr is not "this" or "that"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, depending on how much work you are willing to do.

You can [use a preprocessor and some macros to map strings to integral identifiers](http://timj.testbit.eu/2007/07/14/13072007-switch-on-strings-in-c-and-c/), giving you a syntax like:

```
switch (SOSID_LOOKUP (sample_string)) {
   case SOSID (hello): printf ("Hello ");   break;
   case SOSID (world): printf ("World! ");  break;
   case 0: default:    printf ("unknown "); break;
}
```

If you can use C++ instead of C, you can use [litb's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb) [template-based string switcher](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/11/fun-with-switch-statements.html), giving you syntax like:

```
 sswitch(s) {
    scase("foo"): {
      std::cout << "s is foo" << std::endl;
      break; // could fall-through if we wanted
    }

    // supports brace-less style too
    scase("bar"):
      std::cout << "s is bar" << std::endl;
      break;

    // default must be at the end
    sdefault():
      std::cout << "neither of those!" << std::endl;
      break;
  }
```