# Why C# supports switch with string and C++ doesn't?

Tags: c#, c++, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why switch statement cannot be applied on strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650162/why-switch-statement-cannot-be-applied-on-strings)

In some post I read that the reason is "the compiler must understand what it means for two values to be equal", but in C# it also doesn't know and just call function similar to `Equals`, so why C++ cannot do it either?

Comment: `C++` also doesn't have a garbage collector while `C#` does.

Comment: [All features are unimplemented by default](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/02/features-are-unimplemented-by-default/).

Comment: C++11 DOES support switch cases with Strings.

Comment: @user1615903: Not it doesn't. "The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or of a class type for which a single non-explicit conversion function to integral or enumeration type exists"

Comment: @MikeSeymour: call it what you want, I still think this is a switch case with strings: http://siliconkiwi.blogspot.fi/2012/04/c11-string-switch.html

Comment: take a look here: [Switch on Strings in C++](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/article.php/c4067/Switch-on-Strings-in-C.htm)

Comment: @user1615903: That's not switching on a string, it's switching on a non-unique value calculated from a string. You still need to compare the strings to avoid false positives from hash collisions.

Comment: @MikeSeymour ... or play the loterry.

Comment: Dear administrators, I read the post you placed in my post before posting this post. The quote I used is from that post and that's why I asked why C++ cannot use the same as C# - calling something like `Equals` method