# something unclear about switch-case

Tags: c, switch-statement

Something about `switch-case` statement is very unclear for me. First of all I could understand the `case` part as an `if` statement, but what dose `switch` do itself? I mean when we pass argument to switch, what happens there?

```
c=getchar();
switch(c)
```

2: Why there is no need to put `;` after switch? What kind of the function is it?
3: How compilers implement `switch-case` statement at the first time? (just `C` or use `assembly`)

4: We can't use `switch-case` like this:

```
switch(string)
{
    case "aaaa":
        ...
    case "bbbb":
        ...
```

we use `if-strcmp` instead. Is it possible to create `switch-case` like statement for string condition? I see some library like `getopt` use struct to handle command line string arguments:

```
{"help",...,'h'},
{"version",...,'v'}
...
```

but I want to use string directly.

Comment: It's just what its syntax should be.

Comment: This article could help - C to assembly: if and switch statements http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/basics/CToAssemblyTranslation3.htm

Comment: thanks for links. @Arjun Sreedharan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> first of all I could understand "case" part as a "if" statement, but what dose switch do itself? I mean when we pass argument to switch, what happens there?

In `case`, there's always a constant. You need to "compare" something with this constant. And `switch(a)` means - *"compare a with:"* and it "compares" it to each `case` statement.

---

> 2: why there is no need to put ";" after switch? what kind of the function is it?

It's not a function. You're not calling `switch` function, you're just starting to write a `switch` statement.

---

> 3: how compilers implement switch-case statement at the first time? (just C or use assembly)

That's platform specific. Sometimes, it's implemented using `jump`s (asm) and offsets.

---

> 4: we can't use switch-case like this:

Because `switch` works only with *integral* types (that is `int`, `enum`, `char`, etc. and *not* `double`, strings, etc.)

Comment: If we aren't calling it so how does it work? could we make something like it or we just create functions?

Comment: @user3433566 - it's just syntax, a statement, a keyword. Just like `if`, `return`, `for`, etc. What do you mean by "how does it work" - byte level, assembly, ..? Yes, you can use `if-else`, instead of `switch`. I don't understand the last part of your question - what functions?

Comment: @ Kiril Kirov thanks to reply. I mean we could use goto and a jump-table to simulate a switch case but I'm not sure it be like a statement. Is that possible to create a new statement in c or not? or my question orginaly is wrong?

Comment: You can write your own function, that does something like this, use `jump`s, or whatever you like, but this will now be a _function_. You cannot create new keywords in `C`. Keywords are part of the language's _syntax_ and you cannot change it. Defining functions is a different thing. Not sure if this helps, but I can't find a better way to explain what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement begins the scope of the cases. Scopes in C/C++ are always bound by curly braces ( `{}` ), specifying the scope of local variables (on the stack) which is used to hold the switch parameter. It hence doesn't need a `;` since it is grammatically much like a while loop.

Compilers implement switchs as direct jump in assembly. This is what makes them really more efficient than ifs (which are mostly compiled as different comparisons in assembly). This is also the reason why you can't use a switch on text. The value of a `char*` is only a pointer, hence cannot be used to correctly identify the target section to execute.

Answer (score 0):

To use strings in switch case() in c what you can do is, to store the possible strings of switch in a string as

```
char * switchstr[]={"abc", "def", "ghi"};
```

then search for the input string in the switchstr[] and use the index of matching string as switch case parameter.
And to know why `strings are not supported in switch case` read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650162/why-switch-statement-cannot-be-applied-on-strings). IT has discussion about why string cant be used directly in switch statement in C/C++.
And also switch case checks for equality and we know in C it is not possible to check the equality of string directly by using `=` sign, instead we need to use strcmp() function.

Answer (score 0):

> first of all I could understand "case" part as a "if" statement, but what dose switch do itself?

The `switch` part sets the expression that is used to compare with the values in the associated `case` labels.

> 2: why there is no need to put ";" after switch? what kind of the function is it?

It is *not* a function; `switch` is a language keyword that is part of the `switch` statement (i.e. the whole `switch`/`case` construct). It is not a function just because it uses parentheses any more than `while(...)` or `if(...)` are functions.

> 3: how compilers implement switch-case statement at the first time? (just C or use assembly)

That is up to the compiler. *How* things are implemented is generally not within the purview of a language standard, only (as precisely as possible) *what* should happen.

In practice, a `switch` statements tend to be implemented with branches if there are only a few `case`s, and with a jump table if there are many.

> 4: we can't use switch-case [with strings]

Because *C* defines the `switch` statement as working with integral types. A string is not an integral type. To provide the kind of functionality you envisage would require adding (at least) “content equality” testing for strings to the core *C* language. To do this consistently in a way that does not break existing code is probably impossible and contrary to the “minimalist” philosophy of *C*.