# Make a Timetable with input and output C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How could I go about creating a program in C++ which would let me input a day which would print a timetable for that day, e.g. Monday = "Mathematics Lecture at 10:00", Tuesday = "Mathematics Tutorial at 12:00 to 14:00". And how could I input a time which would then output the lecture for that day, e.g. if I entered 10:00, it would output "Monday, Mathematics Lecture".
I'm still learning the basics so unsure of how to construct it and what to use

Comment: You may want to use a `struct` that contains a time field and a description field.  Maybe expand to starting time, ending time and event description (use `std::string`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your beginner level, you'll probably want to create a series of if/else statements, and have the output be determined by what the user enters. The code for that would look a bit like this:

```
string day;
cout << "Please enter a day of the week: ";
cin >> day;

if(day == "Monday"){
   //output something
}
else if(day == "Tuesday"){
   //output something different
}
else if(day == "Wednesday")...
```

...and so on and so forth.

You could also use a `switch` statement (you can learn more about that here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-statement-cc/). A switch statement for this program would look a bit like this:

```
string day;

switch(day){
case "Monday":
    //output something
    break;
case "Tuesday":
    //output something different
    break;
case "Wednesday":...
```

...and so on and so forth. At your level, your best bet might just be using if/else statements though. Whichever way you choose to do it, good luck!

EDIT: Typo fixes.

Comment: Did you know that `switch-case` cannot be used with `std::string`?
([proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650162/why-the-switch-statement-cannot-be-applied-on-strings)).

Comment: @JohnCvelth I actually was not aware; thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are beginner, I’ll tell you what to look into (given your level).  To get input from the user, you can use `cin`.  To decide what to output, you can use `if`, `else if`, and `else` statements.  A better alternative would be the `switch` statement.  To actually output the response, use `cout`.

Just do a Google search on these and you should be able to construct your program easily.  Of course there are better ways to do this... but for a beginner program that is what you should look into.