# How to implement universal switch/case, which can work for general C++ types as well and syntactically similar?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, comparison, c++17, syntactic-sugar

In C/C++, `switch/case` compares only an integral type with a compile time constants. It's not possible to use them to compare user/library defined types like `std::string` with runtime values.  [Why the switch statement cannot be applied on strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650162/why-the-switch-statement-cannot-be-applied-on-strings)

Can we implement **look-a-like** `switch/case` which gives similar syntactic sugar and serves the purpose of avoiding plain `if/else` comparisons.

---

```
struct X { 
  std::string s;
  bool operator== (const X& other) const { return s == other.s; }
  bool operator== (const std::string& other) const { return s == other; }
};
```

In nutshell, one should be able to run this `switch/case`, if there is an `operator==` defined for a type `X`. i.e.:

```
X x1{"Hello"}, x2{"World"};
switch(x1)
{
  // compare literal or any different type for which `==` is defined
  case "Hello": std::cout << "Compared 'Hello'\n"; break;     
  // cases/default appear in between and also can fall-through without break
  default:      std::cout << "Compared 'Default'\n"; 
  // compare compiletime or runtime created objects
  case x2:    { std::cout << "Compared 'World'\n"; break; }
}
```

I know above is not possible as it is. But anything similar looking will be good.
This question is inspired by a way demonstrated in this [blogspot: *Fun with switch statements*](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/).

Comment: You can use `enum`s to simulate a word. I'm not sure that it would suffice for you though.

Comment: Why do you want to use switch/case, especially with fallthrough? I don't think that C++ switch/case should be called a "syntactic sugar" given that it is basically a goto in disguise.

Comment: @VTT, `swich/case` is amalgamation of `if/else` & `goto`. It's a better readable alternative for pure == comparison. Fall through is very useful in many practical situations. In nutshell, it's desirable to have regular `switch/case` for runtime objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Implentation:

```
#define CONCATE_(X,Y) X##Y
#define CONCATE(X,Y) CONCATE_(X,Y)
#define UNIQUE(NAME) CONCATE(NAME, __LINE__)

#define MSVC_BUG(MACRO, ARGS) MACRO ARGS
#define NUM_ARGS_2(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, TOTAL, ...) TOTAL
#define NUM_ARGS_1(...) MSVC_BUG(NUM_ARGS_2, (__VA_ARGS__))
#define NUM_ARGS(...) NUM_ARGS_1(__VA_ARGS__, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
#define VA_MACRO(MACRO, ...) MSVC_BUG(CONCATE, (MACRO, NUM_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)))(__VA_ARGS__)

#define switch_(X) for(struct { static_assert(not std::is_pointer<decltype(X)>::value, "No Pointers!"); \
              const decltype(X)& VALUE_; enum { CASES, DEFAULT, COMPARED } IS_ = CASES; } VAR_{X}; \
                       VAR_.IS_ != VAR_.COMPARED; \
                       VAR_.IS_ == VAR_.DEFAULT or (VAR_.IS_ = VAR_.COMPARED))

#define default_ {}} if(VAR_.IS_ == VAR_.COMPARED or VAR_.IS_ == VAR_.DEFAULT or \
                        ((VAR_.IS_ = VAR_.DEFAULT) and false)) \
                     { VAR_.IS_ = VAR_.COMPARED; CONCATE(default,__LINE__)

#define case_(...) VA_MACRO(case_, __VA_ARGS__)
#define case_1(X)    {}} if(VAR_.IS_ == VAR_.COMPARED or VAR_.VALUE_ == X) \
                         { VAR_.IS_ = VAR_.COMPARED; CONCATE(case,__LINE__)
#define case_2(X,OP) {}} if(VAR_.IS_ == VAR_.COMPARED or VAR_.VALUE_ OP X) \
                         { VAR_.IS_ = VAR_.COMPARED; CONCATE(case,__LINE__)
```

#### Usage:

```
X x1{"Hello"}, x2{"World"};
switch_(x1)
{{ // <--- MUST
  case_("Hello"):   std::cout << "Compared 'Hello'\n"; break;
  default_:         std::cout << "Compared 'Default'\n";
  case_(x2):      { std::cout << "Compared 'World'\n"; break; }
  case_("World"): { std::cout << "Duplicate 'World' again!\n"; break; } // duplicate
}}
```

#### Notes:

- Purpose for `{{ }}` -- is to fix a scenario, where 2 or more statements under `case_` are appearing without enclosing user provided `{}`. This could have resulted in certain statements always executing irrespective of whichever `case_` is true.
- Higher the `default_` placed, better the runtime performance. Putting it lower may make more comparisons when no cases are valid.
- Duplicate cases will compile but only the 1st case will be executed. This duplicate case issue can be fixed/checked by producing a runtime `abort()`, if one is ready to go through every case more than once.
- If one is ready forego syntactic sugar of colon `:`, i.e. `case(X)` instead of `case(X):`, then the `CONCATE` macro is not needed. Retaining colons usually gives compiler warning of unused labels (`-Wunused-label`)
- This utility can be extended for other comparisons such as `<`, `>=`, `!=`, or any such operator; For that we have to add extra argument to `switch_` macro; e.g. `OP` and that has to be placed in `case_` macro as `VAR_ OP X`
- For C++03 compatibility, use `make_pair` inside the `for` loop after declaring a `struct UNIQUE(Type) { enum { ... }; };`
- Arrays and string pointer can be compared with below utility:

---

```
template<typename T>
struct Compare
{
  const T& this_;
  template<typename T_, size_t SIZE>
  bool
  operator== (const T_ (&other)[SIZE]) const
  {
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(this_), decltype(other)>::value, "Array size different!");
    return ::memcmp(this_, other, SIZE);
  }
};
template<>
struct Compare<const char*>
{
  const char* const this_;
  bool operator== (const char other[]) const { return (0 == ::strcmp(this_, other)); }
};
#define COMPARE(X) Compare<decltype(X)>{X}
```

**Usage**: `switch_(COMPARE(var)) {{ }}`.

#### [Demo](http://ideone.com/oUuGSk)

Comment: Using `or` and `and` instead of `||` and `&&` is one possible reason for the downvotes

Comment: I agree they're valid, but that doesn't mean they're appropriate to use - they exist only to support keyboards / character sets without `|` or `&`, which isn't a problem that should exist any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get around the fact that the switch cases must be `constexpr` integrals so `case x2:` will not work. It must be `constexpr`.

One way to emulate switching on `constexpr` strings could be to use a `constexpr` hashing function.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

// boilerplate - any constexpr hashing function would do
inline constexpr uint64_t ror64(uint64_t v, int r) {
    return (v >> r) | (v << (64 - r));
}

inline constexpr uint64_t rrmxmx2(uint64_t v) {
    v ^= ror64(v, 27) ^ ror64(v, 52);
    v *= 0x9fb21c651e98df25UL;
    v ^= ror64(v, 27) ^ ror64(v, 52);
    v *= 0xc20bf31a8f5694c9UL;
    return v ^ (v >> 28);
}

class Checksum {
    static constexpr uint64_t INC1 = 0x3C6EF372FE94F82BUL; // sqrt(5)
    static constexpr uint64_t INC2 = 0xA54FF53A5F1D36F1UL; // sqrt(7)

    uint64_t words = 0;
    uint64_t s[4] = {INC1, INC2, INC1, INC2};

public:
    constexpr Checksum(const uint64_t S[4], uint64_t Words) :
        words(Words), s{S[0], S[1], S[2], S[3]} {}
    constexpr Checksum() {}
    constexpr Checksum(const char* str) {
        while(*str != '\0') {
            update(*str);
            ++str;
        }
    }

    bool operator==(const Checksum& rhs) const {
        return words == rhs.words && s[0] == rhs.s[0] && s[1] == rhs.s[1] &&
               s[2] == rhs.s[2] && s[3] == rhs.s[3];
    }
    inline bool operator!=(const Checksum& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }
    constexpr void update(uint64_t w) {
        uint64_t tmp = s[0] + rrmxmx2(s[1] + (s[2] ^ s[3]));
        s[0] = s[1];
        s[1] = s[2];
        s[2] = s[3] + ++words;
        s[3] = tmp + w;
    }
    constexpr size_t finalize() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
            uint64_t tmp = s[0] + rrmxmx2(s[1] + (s[2] ^ s[3]));
            s[0] = s[1];
            s[1] = s[2];
            s[2] = s[3] + i;
            s[3] = tmp;
        }
        return s[0];
    }
};

constexpr size_t checksum(const char* str) {
    return Checksum(str).finalize();
}
// end of boilerplate

int main() {
    std::string word;
    size_t hash;

    do {
        std::cout << "enter a word: ";
        std::cin >> word;

        hash = checksum(word.c_str());

        switch(hash) {
        case checksum("foo"):
            std::cout << "excellent\n";
            break;
        case checksum("bar"):
            std::cout << "very good\n";
            break;
        case checksum("baz"):
            std::cout << "well done\n";
            break;
        case checksum("secret"):
            std::cout << "extremely gifted\n";
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "invalid word\n";
        }
    } while(hash != checksum("quit"));
}
```

Comment: How would this help to *"compare compiletime or runtime created objects"*?

Comment: @VTT I'm not sure I understand the question. The example is switching on hashes of objects created in runtime and compares it with hashes created compiletime. Ah... `x2` ... no that won't fly. correct. Will add note.

Comment: OP wants to be able to compare runtime object with other runtime objects.

Comment: @VTT Yes, I noticed that was part of it. Added note at the top.

Comment: Also what about hash collisions?

Comment: @VTT That's a generic problem with non-identity hashes so one needs to pick one that's passed rigorous testing (i.e. TestU01 and PractRand etc). The above one is good but can easily be replaced. The actual hashing function used in the example was just an example.

Comment: Performing equality compare `if ("..." != x2)` for each case with a `goto` into `default` brach would be quite nasty.

Comment: @VTT If one starts creating a switch/case construct and finds him/herself adding misc. `if`s to it, using such a construct was probably the wrong decision. That seemed to me like a minor part of the question. As long as one wants to use the switch/case construct in a normal way - but with non-integral (but still `constexpr`) objects the above works, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Using such construct with objects known at compile time is kinda pointless, since it using enumerators would be much simpler. Using such construct with arbitrary runtime objects would require performing mandatory equality compare for each case.

Comment: @VTT Sure, an option could be to use an `unordered_map<std::string, int>` with strings mapped to enums and switch on that instead. That could be an answer on its own. I still think this answer answers OP:s question "_Can we implement look-a-like switch/case..._"  with yes and shows an example of a working implementation.

Comment: @user7860670 ... and an `unordered_map<string, int>` wouldn't automatically have fewer collisions.