# Why I can't use chars in switch cases?

Tags: c++, char, switch-statement, case

I have to make a calculator which will based on user's input, do specific operation. First of the input must be some kind of operator(`+`, `-`, `*`, etc.) and after the code checks which one of those is user's `choice`. I declared those operators as `char`, but my code editor says that I can't put `char` variables as case statements...What should I do?
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
char choice = "+", "*", "-", "/";
int a, b;
float outcome;

scanf("%c", &choice);

switch (choice)
{
    case "+":
        scanf("d% d%", &a, &b);
        outcome = a + b;
        printf("%.1f", outcome);
        break;
    case "*":
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        outcome = a * b;
        printf("%.1f", outcome); 
        break;
    case "-":
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        outcome = a - b;
        printf("%.1f", outcome);
        break;
    case "/":
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        outcome = a / b;
        printf("%.1f", outcome);
        break;

   }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"+"` is a *string*, not the single character literal `'+'`. Note the difference between double and single quotes.

Comment: `char choice = "+", "*", "-", "/";` <= does this even compile?

Comment: @crashmstr yes it does compile, but it certainly doesn't do what OP expects it to do. Short explanation: comma operator. Long explanation: The address of the last string literal is implicitly converted to an integer and truncated to a char's size. Should cause a shuckload of compiler warnings, but technically is legal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the switch statement cannot be applied on strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650162/why-the-switch-statement-cannot-be-applied-on-strings)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `char`s in `switch` but `"+"` and others are string literals not character literals, that would be `'+'`.

There are other problems in your code. For example it is not clear what you expect this to do (already fixed the quotes):

```
char choice = '+', '*', '-', '/';
```

A `char` is a single character.

Your code looks like C but not like C++. If you are actually using C++, you could use `std::string` and its `find` method, for example like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string choices = "+*-/";

    auto choice = choices.find('*');

    switch (choice){
        case 0: std::cout << "you chose +";break;
        case 1: std::cout << "you chose *";break;
        case 2: std::cout << "you chose -";break;
        case 3: std::cout << "you chose /";break;
        default: std::cout << "invalid operator";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are not chars, these are string literals.

Use '+' instead of "+".