Why do we need to refer to the object to access a pointer to a member function?
class Harl {
    private:
        void debug( void );
        void info( void );
        void warning( void );
        void error( void );
    public:
        void complain( std::string level );
};

void Harl::complain( std::string level )
{
    int i;
    std::string levels[4];
    void (Harl::*d_ptr)() = &Harl::debug;
    void (Harl::*i_ptr)() = &Harl::info;
    void (Harl::*w_ptr)() = &Harl::warning;
    void (Harl::*e_ptr)() = &Harl::error;

    levels[0] = "DEBUG";
    levels[1] = "INFO";
    levels[2] = "WARNING";
    levels[3] = "ERROR";
    void (Harl::*p_levels[4])();

    p_levels[0] = d_ptr;
    p_levels[1] = i_ptr;
    p_levels[2] = w_ptr;
    p_levels[3] = e_ptr;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (level == levels[i])
            break;
    }
    (this->*(p_levels[i]))();
}

int main()
{
    Harl harl1;
    Harl harl2;
    Harl harl3;
    Harl harl4;

    harl4.complain("ERROR");
    harl1.complain("WARNING");
    harl2.complain("DEBUG");
    harl3.complain("INFO");
}

i'm already invoking the function from the object in the main function, and when i need to invoke the member function i need to simply call the function like this :
debug();

but to call the member function from the pointer to member function i need to specify the object using this pointer. why ?
i tried :
*(p_levels[i]))()

I expect the program to know which object I am in because I am invoking the complain function from that object.

How is the 'this' pointer used as an argument of a member function

Are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650162/why-cant-the-switch-statement-be-applied-to-strings

Are you asking why is there no rule to use 'this' implicitly in dereferenceng a pointer-to-member expression, if it happens inside a member function"?

A "naked" member function pointer won't get the this->* implicitly.  Other member functions get a this-> implicitly in that context.  A this-> is not a this->*.

@IgorG yes, Exactly

@Eljay The dereferencing here is for the pointer to the member function, resulting in this->*. However, when calling the member function directly, we use this->. Is that the difference, or am I mistaken?

Correct.  The -> is a different operator than ->*.


I expect the program to know which object I am in because I am invoking the complain function from that object.

You can think of a pointer to a member function as a pointer to a free function with extra argument. E.g. a pointer to a member function void foo(int) of a class Bar can be considered a free function with the following signature: void foo(Bar*, int).
The Bar* argument is what this equals to in the body of the function, and, as you can see, it's not bound to the function rigidly, thus you can specify different objects as this first argument and you are not limited to specific context when invoking a member function through a pointer. Thus, the compiler cannot know in advance which this argument you are planning to use in every scenario and requires you to specify it explicitly.
You are, however, free to bind specific this to such a pointer and use it as a free function later:
auto boundFoo = std::bind(&Bar::foo, this, std::placeholder::_1);

boundFoo(1); // can now be called as a free function 


Thank you for your response. In the case above, should I specify the object when calling a member function directly without using pointer to member function?

@MAROUAN The object returned from a std::bind is a functor structure, you can use it directly, but that won't allow you to store functors referring to different member functions in the same container. For that you may employ type erasure technique and replace auto keyword with std::function (as long as your functions have the same signature)
